# Building a mini scale Air Conditioner

Tags: thermodynamics

So I am building a I think one can call it air conditioner System for my Ants.
But it won't really start to work. In my first run, I tried to transport the cold air into the living area of my ants, untill I remembered the elementary physic basics that "coldness is just the absence of heat, and I supposed that it can't quite work to "transport the absence of heat into a heatened body". So I started a new run, now trying to move away the warm air and replace it with the cold air.

This is what my current Setup looks like:

[image: Photo of setup]
<sup>In the reflection encased box sits an peltier element cooling system very similiar to an CPU water cooler. It cools the inside of that box down to up to 20°C less than the room around it.</sup>

The Problem is: In the glascube the temperature measured still doesn't change by even a single degree, yet. There is a perceived cold airstream between the pipe connection and the tube connection, but I can't tell if it is even real or as such just perceived.

(This has been tested with an sealed and with air vents at different positions. This was rather try and error than really a aimed test)

I made this sketch, to hopefully make it easier to understand what is to be seen on the first picture.

[image: a sketch to clarify]

The Fan within the "AC"-box is just directed to the tube, while the fan in the pipe is encased within the pipe.

So is there any basical misunderstanding of how I can get the glasbox cooled with this system?
Or is there just a little detail I am executing wrong?

I am grateful for your help already in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to consider either installing a [Peltier cooler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_cooling), which is nice and small and could be mounted to the ant-box.

Another cool gadget is a simple expansion cooler, where forced air goes thru a tube to a tube of larger diameter. [Vortex](https://www.nexflow.com/blog/vortex-tubes-use-compressed-air-generate-cold-hot-air-simultaneously/) . I once used a micro-version which looped the airflow (internally) to pre-cool the incoming air; we achieved subzero cold-end temperatures.  Sadly, I can't find one commercially listed, though there may be some out there.

Or, perhaps, a  [heat pipe](https://thermocoolcorp.com/project/heat-pipes/) which is basically a "heat pump"

Comment: Well, The AC box, contains peltier coolers, the problem with mounting them to the antbox was, that I could no way the heat gathered on the other side guide away without it reentering the ant box. So I tried to make this happen in a seperated and far away box.